# Switching branches prompts to save file

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Well now I seem to have gone and gotten things all messed up.

I'm trying to learn how Git works and how to use it in a Visual Studio/TFS 2015.3 environment.

Here's the problem: when I create a branch and make a change in it—for example adding a new `SomeClass` class—VS now asks me whether I want to save the changed project when I double-click to switch branches. This behavior is new—previously I could switch branches without such a prompt.

Bear with me here... I need to give you a long history so you'll know the entire context.

I managed to get a VS solution synced with a remote repo. I ran my first TFS build and I was absolutely elated. However, the build produced a warning that no tests were run. Fair enough; I hadn't included a test project. So I created a new local branch called `add-test-project` and added the project.

I found that in VS I could switch back and forth between `master` and `add-test-project` by double-clicking each one. I noticed that the `master` branch didn't include the test project, but the `add-test-project` branch did. That made sense; I hadn't merged anything yet.

So I did the merge/commit/pull request/sync thing (I don't remember how or in which order) and it seemed to have worked—the build didn't register the warning this time.

(Side note: when I did the pull request I was a bit disappointed to see that VS opened the corresponding TFS page in my default browser—I would have wanted to do this all within the IDE.)

I've decided to skip the whole pull request thing because 1) I want to stay in the IDE and 2) I'm working solo, so it's an unnecessary step. And this is what I think has ultimately led to my trouble.

I then did a few more branch/sync/commit/merge cycles (like I said, I don't recall nor am I exactly sure in which order I did/should do them—and each cycle had a different sequence I'm sure). Now I can't switch branches without being prompted to save changes. And the changes are present in both branches.

Has my local Git repo become corrupted somehow? I tried using File Explorer to delete the `.git` and `.vs` hidden folders, reopening VS and re-cloning the repo, but the issue persists.

How can I get things back to where they were, where I could switch branches to see the state of the code that was specific to the current branch? Maybe somehow remove all commits from the server? But I'm not finding a way to do that.

I'm sure I could straighten this out with the 'scorched-earth solution,' e.g. wipe everything out and start from scratch, but I'd like to know what I did wrong (and how to fix it) so I can avoid doing it again.

**EDIT**

It's worth mentioning that now things have gone so badly that when I make a change in a class file—e.g. add a constructor—VS no longer places a red checkmark next to that file. Something has *really* gone sideways here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I was hosting a comedy of errors.

First I'll explain the checkmarks problem: it turned out I'd re-cloned to an entirely different location, so I didn't even have the correct solution open. So instead of deleting only the `.git` and `.vs` folders earlier, I should have deleted everything locally and started from scratch by re-cloning to the original location.

Now for the save file prompt problem: I hadn't committed the change to my local repo. Once I did that I could switch back and forth between branches and the changes reflected as expected.

And now I'm pretty sure I've got the correct sequence down:

1. New branch
2. Make desired coding changes
3. Local commit
4. Local merge to master
5. Push to remote

If I'm incorrect with this sequence would someone say so or if I'm correct confirm. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've also established a new rule for myself: use the same name for the local repo as for the remote.

Comment: Yup, gotta commit (or stash, but that's a completely different command) your changes locally before changing branches. And yeah, that's the correct sequence.